# change to original image once the blur image in bought via in App purchase

Tags: objective-c, ios4, iphone-developer-program

I've made a blur images of my app which can be upgraded to original images via In App Purchase, and I want to know how can I change my image once the blur image is bought.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Since you can't affect the bundle, you should move your blurred images once you're app is installed to the `Library` directory of the app. Once the customer chooses to upgrade, you should download and replace the blurred images with the original images in the `Library` directory.

Comment: Thanks for kind reply. I didn't get you exactly. Can you send me some sample code?